# Error al lanzar script cada minuto desde tarea que se ejecuta cada 10 minutos en Heroku scheduler

Tags: php, heroku

El plan activo de Heroku permite lanzar las tareas cada 10 minutos, por lo que se intenta forzar la ejecución del código cada minuto desde el propio script php, lanzado en modo CLI con el add-on heroku Scheduler Advanced Scheduler:

```
$start = time();
while ((time() - $start) <= 9*60)
{
    $start_loop = time();
    //código a ejecutar
    sleep(max(0, 60-(time() - $start_loop)));
}
```

El código parece funcionar, es simple y tiene un control de errores exhaustivo. Aún así de vez en cuando llega un correo de error indicando que una de las tareas programadas no se ha podido ejecutar correctamente.
Cómo se puede evitar generar los mensajes de error ocasionales?
Se podría mejorar la solución para ejecutar un código con intervalos de tiempo inferiores a los intervalos de ejecución del archivo php que lo contiene?

Comment: No creo que lo correcto sea buscar una forma de ignorar las errores, sino, determinar a qué se deben y corregirlos. ¿Has revisado el log de errores para ver qué error es y por qué ocurre?

Comment: No tengo acceso al log de errores. Se ha estado revisando por dos compañeros pero no parecen haber localizado el problema. La mejor forma en que puedo ayudar es usando o mejorando este código :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Teniendo en cuenta los siguientes puntos:

- El código funciona perfectamente después de varios meses monitoreado.
- No faltan datos en el entorno que recibe el resultado del script cada minuto.
- La tarea se está ejecutando correctamente cada minuto dentro del plan de 10 minutos, que es el único disponible.

Finalmente la solución ha sido **bloquear la generación de los correos de error directamente en la llamada al script**:

```
php ruta.php || echo "agur"
```

Si alguien puede mejorar mi respuesta genial (procuraré que se aplique la mejora sugerida), pero por ahora... un problema menos :-)